# JavaScript, Redux: array not taking value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to get some statistics and problems for a user using a Redux action and pass it to a React component. The problem is, I have the array of objects `curPageExercisesMarked`, which I use for the pagination of the page, but it does not take the values I assign it to.

The stranger thing is that the other fields in the Redux store get updated, but not this one. I tried consoling the object in the action, but it just prints this: [image: Array of object in console]

It is important to mention that I am doing something similar in another action, using the exact same assignment and it works there. I've lost already an hour trying to figure this thing out so any help is welcomed.

The Redux action:

```
export const setStatistics = (
problems,
problemsSolved,
filter = ''
) => dispatch => {
let payload = {
subject1: 0,
subject2: 0,
subject3: 0,
total: 0,
exercisesMarked: [],
curPageExercisesMarked: []
};
for (let i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
  if (problems[i].S === '1' && problemsSolved.includes(problems[i]._id)) {
   payload.subject1++;
   payload.total++;
   payload.exercisesMarked.push(problems[i]);
  } else if (
   problems[i].S === '2' &&
   problemsSolved.includes(problems[i]._id)
  ) {
   payload.subject2++;
   payload.total++;
   payload.exercisesMarked.push(problems[i]);
  } else if (
   problems[i].S === '3' &&
   problemsSolved.includes(problems[i]._id)
  ) {
   payload.subject3++;
   payload.total++;
   payload.exercisesMarked.push(problems[i]);
  }
 }

 payload.curPageExercisesMarked = payload.exercisesMarked.slice(0, 10);

 dispatch({
  type: SET_USER_STATISTICS,
  payload
 });
};
```

The redux reducer:

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
const { type, payload } = action;
switch (type) {
case SET_USER_STATISTICS:
  return {
    ...state,
    exercisesMarked: payload.exercisesMarked,
    curPageExercisesMarked: payload.curPageExercisesMarked,
    subject1: payload.subject1,
    subject2: payload.subject2,
    subject3: payload.subject3,
    total: payload.total
  };
 case CHANGE_PAGE_MARKED:
  return {
    ...state,
    page: payload,
    curPageExercisesMarked: state.exercisesMarked.slice(
      (payload - 1) * state.pages_count,
      payload * state.pages_count
    )
  };
 default:
  return state;
 }
}
```

This is the part that does not function:
`payload.curPageExercisesMarked = payload.exercisesMarked.slice(0, 10);`

**EDIT**

I've discovered that if I go a component which loads all the problems and come back to this component, it actually gets the correct value.
Now, the interesting is that I do get the same problems here as well. Is it the way I use React Hook?

This is the part where I call the redux action in the react component:

```
const Dashboard = ({
problems: { problems },
auth: { user },
getProblems,
dashboard: {
curPageExercisesMarked,
page,
exercisesMarked,
pages_count,
subject1,
subject2,
subject3,
total
},
setStatistics
}) => {
useEffect(() => {
 if (problems === null) {
   getProblems();
 } else if (user !== null) {
   setStatistics(problems, user.problemsSolved);
 }
}, [problems, user]);
// rest of the code
}
```

Comment: can you console log "payload.exercisesMarked.slice(0, 10);" this part and see if this is even getting data you are expecting to assign it to other one

Comment: Yes, it does get what it should get. It looks like this:
`[{..}]
 -> 0: {help1: Array(1), help2:Array(1), ...(rest of object)
-> 1:...
...`
So it does get what it should get

Comment: can you console log "payload.curPageExercisesMarked" inside reducer case and see if it is there

Comment: It is the same as in the picture from the post. The thing is, I tried updating `payload.curPageExercisesMarked` with push in a for, but the same thing happens. It doesn't even add one object to the array

Comment: Personally, I would step through the code in the console using breakpoints. Have you considered using Array.map to loop over your problems, I think this would clean up your code some and help to debug.

Comment: what if you just assign simple array to curPageExercusesMarked like "["a", "b", "c"];" and see if that get passed if so, then there is something else in code that is setting this to empty object, because I think it has something to do with your other case " case CHANGE_PAGE_MARKED:"

Comment: It still becomes empty. Check my Edit, it may help

Comment: check where ever you dispatch "CHANGE_PAGE_MARKED" I would start there and see if you need to dispatch both actions at same time, and see if this "state.exercisesMarked" has data in it in that case, if so then check your slice because use of payload - 1 doesnt make sense to me

Comment: I actually did it. I did it so, if problems is null in the action, I dispatch the action to fetch it and await for axios. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first simplify code as below. Update/Print `console.log(JSON.stringify(payload))`. I think `if(problemsSolved.includes(problems[i]._id))` not working as expected

```
export const setStatistics = (
  problems,
  problemsSolved,
  filter = ""
) => dispatch => {
  let payload = {
    subject1: 0,
    subject2: 0,
    subject3: 0,
    total: 0,
    exercisesMarked: [],
    curPageExercisesMarked: []
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
    if(problemsSolved.includes(problems[i]._id)) {
      payload["subject"+ problems[i].S]++
      payload.total++;
      payload.exercisesMarked.push(problems[i]);
    }
  }
  payload.curPageExercisesMarked = payload.exercisesMarked.slice(0, 10);

  dispatch({
    type: SET_USER_STATISTICS,
    payload
  });
};
```

// Also

```
case SET_USER_STATISTICS:
  return {
    ...state,
    ...payload
  };
```

Comment: Thank you! i am new to the way you can simplify things in JavaScript.
Also, I did print my payload in the way you mentioned and, strangely, here it has the value it needs

Comment: You know, even the render renders it for a split second, then it disappears

Comment: Meaning, it retriggers this function and that time data is blank. Somethig async is causing issue. Dont mix side-effect with sync code.

Comment: But if I log the variables, nothing is empty/ undefined / null

Comment: yeah! coz default value is `let payload = {
subject1: 0,
subject2: 0,
subject3: 0,
total: 0,
exercisesMarked: [],
curPageExercisesMarked: []
};`

Comment: if u can create sanbox. i can help

Comment: I actually did it. I did it so, if problems is null in the action, I dispatch the action to fetch it and await for axios. Thank you for your suggestions!